# Accumulators in the XPath: is it possible? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, accumulate

I'm trying to do an accumulation in the XPath, is it possible?

Look at my code yet:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.imdb.com/user/ur33778891/watchlist?ref_=wt_nv_wl_all_0')
wait = (WebDriverWait, 10)
x = 1
while True:

        try:

                film = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "((//h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a)[%d]"  % x).text
                x = x + 1
                print(film)
```

The thing is, I'm trying to go to the IMDB website, inside a user watchlist, and get the name film by film with this method, but as I see it's not possible to use %d for this purpose, is there anything that the Selenium allows that could do the job?

PS: Nor string nor number is working.

The thing is: if you open the IMDB watchlist, there will be a list of films, and the XPath of then are the same //h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a, but I was thinking about how to select then individually, I know that it can be done like this:

```
  //h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a [1] #this will select the first movie
  //h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a [2] #this will select the second movie
```

Now, is there a way to do this automatically? I was thinking with the accumulators, instead of the [1] I was going to put the [x] and determine as x = x + 1.

Comment: "name film by film" is a little confusing. Can you provide an example?

Comment: i edited, see if you can get it now.

Comment: Yes, thats better! ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for that the following code:

```
xpath = "//h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a[{}]".format(x)
```

After that use like this:

```
film = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).text
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: It went perfectly, you this missed a ")" in the end.

Comment: @LuísHenriqueMartins, I just removed all brackets. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you are starting with *x = 1* so you can use the index as follows :

```
film = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='lister-item-header']/a")[x].get_attribute("innerHTML")
```